# Search bar in top of ViewContoller with UITableView and reload data

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uisearchbar, searchbar

I got ViewController and `UITableViewController` in it. In top of my VC I got Search bar. I need to connect Search bar with my tableView.

```
  @interface MessageViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

//.m

```
 self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, kRowHeight)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:0.7];
self.searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];


#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self doSearch];

return YES;
}
```

Why I not get updated `tableView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing the search try to invoke `[self.tableView reloadData];`, at the bottom of your `doSearch` method to reload the content of your `tableView`.

Comment: I do it in kReloadMessageViewControllerScreen

Comment: Do I need to tell searchDisplayController where is DataSourse for searching?

Comment: If they are related, yes you do.

Comment: I'm really glad you did it! Thanks for all the comments.